# Get the type of concrete class from IList<Interface> reference

Tags: c#, list, interface

I want to get the Type of the object from the reference of the IList

```
public interface A
{
}  
public class B : A
{
//Some properties
}
public class C : A
{
//Some properties
}
List<B> b = new List<B>();
IList<A> a = new List<A>(b);
Type type = a.GetType();
if(type == typeof(IList<B>)){
//some code
}else if(type == typeof(IList<C>)){
//Some code
}
```

The type should be a List of B as the object of List of B is created.

```
IList<A>
```

Comment: You mean you want to take a generic list of A, and create separate lists containing the B items and C items from A?

Comment: Yes...Right now List of A can contain either B items or A items... I want to know which type of items A contains.

Comment: `a.First().GetType()` will tell you the type of the first item, so then you just need to check all the others are the same type: `a.All(i => i.GetType() == a.First().GetType()`. Not sure what you how to plan to treat a list with a mixture of elements of different types.

Comment: I don't understand the intention of the code snippet.  But I'd guess you are looking for a.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0].

Comment: @DylanNicholson a.First() is not working because of the List<Interface>

Comment: You have `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: @DylanNicholson yes i have. Why you delete your answer. It was the most appropriate answer till now :). As i said earlier, List of A will only contain either Items of Type B or C,It will not contain the mixture of both. I just don't want to iterate through the list to get the type of the objects it contain.

Comment: There is a smell here. But you can do `if (a.All(x => x is B)) { /* some code */ } else if (a.All(x => x is C)) { /* Some code */ } else { ... }`. This is using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this;

```
            List<B> b = new List<B>()
            {
                new B {Sample = "Sample" }
            };
            IList<A> a = new List<A>(b);
            var typeList = a.GroupBy(x => x.GetType()).Select(type => type.Key).ToList(); 
            // Getting different types and grouping them
            if (typeList.Count == 1)
            {
                if (typeList[0] == typeof(B))
                {
                    //some code
                }
                else if (typeList[0] == typeof(C))
                {
                    //Some code
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //There are multiple different types in the list
            }
```

You want to compare list elements which has implementation type and you can compare it by grouping items as `Type`.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't work. What would you expect ? You are creating a list and add items which is implementation type inside it and if there is no "item"  to add, you can't know its type. You are trying to get type "nothing". It is not possible.

Comment: You do not need `GroupBy` when you do not really use the items in each group. In that case, you can do `var typeList = a.Select(x => x?.GetType()).Distinct().ToList();` instead. When I do `?.`, null items in the list `a` will be represented by a null `Type` the resulting type list.

Comment: Thank you for information, but i don't want to discuss GroupBy vs Distinct or possible null items right now. Because the OP provide more detail about what is achieving ? It is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, but it only works with no empty list.

```
public static void Main()
{
    IList<B> b = new List<B>(){ new B() };
    IList<A> a = new List<A>(b);

    if(a.All(x=>x is B))
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    else if(a.All(x=>x is C))
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("A");
}
```

Comment: Neither `List<T>` nor `IList<T>` is covariant in `T`. So this tests nothing (unless the runtime type implements `IList<>` twice, but that is not relevant here (or ever!)).

Comment: Yes, see my changes, a means check items.

Comment: After edit, the answer is unrelated to what it was before. The idea with `.All(x => x is B)` will work (looks like my comment to the question above). But of course, if the list is mixed with some `B` instances and some `C` instances, we will end in the last `else` branch. It could be better to just `foreach (var x in a) { if (x is B b) { ... } ... }`, that is, to decide for each item in the list what case to do. Just like in a currently deleted answer by "john".